# Method of proof of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\tfrac{\coth n\pi}{n^7}=\tfrac{19}{56700}\pi^7$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

The following formula was stated by Ramanujan:

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\coth n\pi}{n^7}=\frac{19\pi^7}{56700}$$

Does anybody know the method of proof of this formula? I know that typically Ramanujan used extensively methods of divergent series, but I cannot see how to attempt a proof of this result. It looks somehow like a relatively simple result, but I can't see what methods might be used to obtain it.

Comment: Take a look at equations (92)-(97) at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html

Comment: I just found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138406/sum-of-series-involving-coth-using-complex-analysis) which computes this sum with complex analysis.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Since $(7)$ from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/143179) is valid for any $z\in\mathbb{C}$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\pi\coth(\pi n)
&=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac1{n+ik}\\
&=\frac1n+2n\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2+k^2}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\pi\coth(\pi n)}{n^7}
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^8}+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{n^6(n^2+k^2)}\\
&=\zeta(8)+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}\left(\frac1{n^6}-\frac1{n^4(n^2+k^2)}\right)\\
&=\zeta(8)+2\zeta(2)\zeta(6)-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}\frac1{n^4(n^2+k^2)}\tag{2}\\
&=\zeta(8)+2\zeta(2)\zeta(6)-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^4}\left(\frac1{n^4}-\frac1{n^2(n^2+k^2)}\right)\\
&=\zeta(8)+2\zeta(2)\zeta(6)-2\zeta(4)\zeta(4)+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^4n^2(n^2+k^2)}\tag{3}\\[6pt]
&=\zeta(8)+2\zeta(2)\zeta(6)-\zeta(4)\zeta(4)\tag{4}\\[12pt]
&=\frac{19\pi^8}{56700}\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
where $(4)$ is the average of $(2)$ and $(3)$. Also. we've used the values of $\zeta(2k)$ computed in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/116212). Thus,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\coth(\pi n)}{n^7}=\frac{19\pi^7}{56700}\tag{6}
$$

Comment: This proof is probably not unique, but I did reinvent it for this question. I haven't tried, but I assume that it can be generalized for other odd exponents. For even exponents, there might be a similar formula involving $\zeta$ at odd integers.

Answer (score 15):

Suppose we seek to show that
$$\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{\coth(n \pi)}{n^7} = \frac{19\pi^7}{56700}.$$

Using $$\coth(x) = \frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{e^x-e^{-x}}
= 1 + 2\frac{e^{-x}}{e^x-e^{-x}}$$
this is the same as
$$2\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{1}{n^7}
\frac{e^{-n\pi}}{e^{n\pi}-e^{-n\pi}}
= -\zeta(7) + \frac{19\pi^7}{56700}.$$

The  sum term may  be evaluated  using harmonic  summation techniques.
Since  this  method  has  not   been  presented  I  will  detail  this
calculation here.

Put $$S(x) =
\sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{1}{n^7} 
\frac{e^{-nx}}{e^{nx}-e^{-nx}}.$$

We will evaluate $S(\pi)$ using a functional equation for $S(x)$ that is obtained by inverting its Mellin transform.

Recall the harmonic sum identity
$$\mathfrak{M}\left(\sum_{k\ge 1} \lambda_k g(\mu_k x);s\right) =
\left(\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{\lambda_k}{\mu_k^s} \right) g^*(s)$$
where $g^*(s)$ is the Mellin transform of $g(x).$

In the present case we have
$$\lambda_k = \frac{1}{k^7}, \quad
\mu_k = k
\quad \text{and} \quad
g(x) = \frac{e^{-x}}{e^x-e^{-x}}.$$

We need the Mellin transform $g^*(s)$ of $g(x)$ which is
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{e^x-e^{-x}} x^{s-1} dx
= \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-2x}}{1-e^{-2x}} x^{s-1} dx
\\ = \int_0^\infty 
\sum_{q\ge 0} e^{-2x} e^{- 2 q x} x^{s-1} dx
=  \sum_{q\ge 0}  \int_0^\infty e^{-2(q+1)x} x^{s-1} dx 
\\= \Gamma(s) \sum_{q\ge 0} \frac{1}{2^s (q+1)^s}
= \frac{1}{2^s} \Gamma(s) \zeta(s)$$
with fundamental strip $\langle 1, \infty\rangle.$

It follows that the Mellin transform $Q(s)$ of the harmonic sum 
$S(x)$ is given by

$$Q(s) = 2^{-s} \Gamma(s) \zeta(s) \zeta(s+7)
\quad\text{because}\quad
\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{\lambda_k}{\mu_k^s} = 
\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{1}{k^7} \frac{1}{k^s}$$
for $\Re(s) > -6.$

The Mellin inversion integral here is
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{3/2-i\infty}^{3/2+i\infty} Q(s)/x^s ds$$
which we evaluate  by shifting it to the left  for an expansion about
zero.

Fortunately the  trivial zeros of  the two zeta function  terms cancel
the poles of  the gamma function term. Shifting to  $\Re(s) = -7 -1/2$
we get
$$S(x) =
\frac{\pi^8}{18900}\frac{1}{x}
- \frac{1}{2} \zeta(7)
+ \frac{\pi^6 x}{5670}
- \frac{\pi^4 x^3}{8100}
+ \frac{\pi^2 x^5}{5670}
+ \frac{4}{45} \zeta'(-6) x^6
+ \frac{1}{18900} x^7
\\+ \frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{-15/2-i\infty}^{-15/2+i\infty} Q(s)/x^s ds.$$

We will turn this into the promised functional equation.

Substitute $s = -6 - t$ in the remainder integral to get
$$- \frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{3/2+i\infty}^{3/2-i\infty}
\frac{1}{2^{-6-t}} 
\Gamma(-6-t) \zeta(-6-t) \zeta(1-t)
x^{t+6} dt$$
which is
$$\frac{x^6}{2\pi i} 
\int_{3/2-i\infty}^{3/2+i\infty}
2^{6+t} \Gamma(-6-t) \zeta(-6-t) \zeta(1-t)
x^t dt$$

In view of  the desired functional equation we  now use the functional
equation  of the Riemann  zeta function  on $Q(s)$  to prove  that the
integrand of the last integral is in fact $-Q(t)/\pi^{6+2t}.$

Start with the functional equation
$$\zeta(1-s) = \frac{2}{2^s\pi^s} 
\cos\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right) \Gamma(s) \zeta(s)$$
and substitute this into $Q(s)$ to obtain
$$Q(s) = 
2^{-s} \frac{\zeta(1-s) 2^s \pi^s}{2\cos\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)}
\zeta(s+7)
= \frac{1}{2} \pi^s \frac{\zeta(s+7)}{\cos\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)}
\zeta(1-s).$$
Apply the functional equation again (this time to $\zeta(s+7)$) to get
$$Q(s) =  \frac{1}{2} \frac{\pi^s}{\cos\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)}
\frac{2}{2^{-6-s} \pi^{-6-s}}
\cos\left(\frac{\pi (-6-s)}{2}\right)
\Gamma(-6-s) \zeta(-6-s) \zeta(1-s)$$
Observe that
$$\frac{\cos\left(-3\pi-\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)}
{\cos\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)}
= - \frac{\cos\left(-\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)}
{\cos\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)} = -1$$ so we finally get
$$Q(s) =  - 2^{6+s} \pi^{6+2s} \Gamma(-6-s) \zeta(-6-s) \zeta(1-s),$$
thus proving the claim.

Return to the remainder integral and re-write it as follows:
$$\frac{(x/\pi)^6}{2\pi i} 
\int_{3/2-i\infty}^{3/2+i\infty}
2^{6+t} \pi^{6+2t} \Gamma(-6-t) \zeta(-6-t) \zeta(1-t)
(x/\pi^2)^t dt.$$
so that  the fact of it being  a multiple of the  defining integral of
$S(x)$ becomes readily apparent.

Using the fact that 
$4/45 \times \zeta'(-6) = -1/2\times\zeta(7)/\pi^6$
we have established the functional equation
$$S(x) =
\frac{\pi^8}{18900}\frac{1}{x}
- \frac{1}{2} \zeta(7)
+ \frac{\pi^6 x}{5670}
- \frac{\pi^4 x^3}{8100}
+ \frac{\pi^2 x^5}{5670}
- \zeta(7) \frac{1}{2\pi^6} x^6
+ \frac{x^7}{18900}
\\ - \frac{x^6}{\pi^6} S(\pi^2/x).$$

Now the value $x=\pi$ is obviously special here and we get
$$S(\pi) = \pi^7 
\left(\frac{1}{18900} + \frac{1}{5670} - \frac{1}{8100}
+ \frac{1}{5670} + \frac{1}{18900}\right) -\zeta(7)- S(\pi)$$
which gives
$$2 S(\pi) = \pi^7 \frac{19}{56700} -\zeta(7)$$
as was to be shown.

The  inspiration  for  this  calculation  is from  the  paper  "Mellin
Transform and its Applications" by Szpankowski.

Comment: Great! I'm ignorant of these techniques though.

Comment: Nicely done. Is there a deeper reason why S(pi) is as special as it is or does that just happen to be that way?

Answer (score 7):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> There is a *straightforward* way to evaluate the
>   $\texttt{initial (k,n)-sum}$ which is the starting point of 
>   [@robjohn](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/991110/85343) fine answer:

\begin{align}
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pi\coth\pars{\pi n} \over n^{7}} & =
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{8}} +
2\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{6}\pars{n^{2} + k^{2}}}
\\[5mm] & =
\zeta\pars{8} +
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\bracks{%
{1 \over n^{6}\pars{n^{2} + k^{2}}} + {1 \over k^{6}\pars{k^{2} + n^{2}}}}
\\[5mm] & =
\zeta\pars{8} +
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}
{k^{6} + n^{6} \over k^{6}n^{6}\pars{n^{2} + k^{2}}} =
\zeta\pars{8} +
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}
{k^{4} - k^{2}n^{2} + n^{4} \over k^{6}n^{6}}
\\[5mm] & =
\zeta\pars{8} +
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{6}}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over k^{2}} -
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{4}}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over k^{4}} +
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{2}}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over k^{6}}
\\[5mm] & =
\zeta\pars{8} + 2\zeta\pars{6}\zeta\pars{2} - \zeta^{2}\pars{4}
\end{align}

Answer (score 6):

In the following a general expression for
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\coth(n\pi)}{n^{4K-1}}
$$
with $K\in\mathbb Z_+$ will be derived.

Consider the following function:
$$
f_k(z)=\frac{\cot z\coth z}{z^{k}}.\tag1
$$
The function has the pole of order $k+2$ at $z=0$ and simple poles at the points $z=n\pi$ and $z=i n\pi$, with $n\in\mathbb Z$, $n\ne0$.

Let us integrate the function along a square contour connecting the following points of the complex plane:
$$\gamma_\nu:\;
(-\nu,-\nu)\to(\nu,-\nu)\to(\nu,\nu)\to(-\nu,\nu)\to   
$$
with $\nu\in\mathbb R,\nu\not\in\mathbb Z,\nu>0$.

By [Cauchy's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem) the exact choice of $\nu\in(n\pi,n\pi+\pi)$ does not matter for the value of the integral. To simplify its estimate for large $n$ 
let $\nu=\left(n+\frac14\right)\pi$. In this case:
$$
|\cot(x\pm i\nu)\coth(x\pm i\nu)|^2=\frac{1+\cot^2x\coth^2\nu}{\cot^2x+\coth^2\nu}\cdot
\underbrace{\frac{1+\coth^2x\cot^2\nu}{\coth^2x+\cot^2\nu}}_{=1}
=\frac{\tan^2x+\coth^2\nu}{1+\tan^2x\coth^2\nu}\le\coth^2\nu.
$$
Due to the symmetry the same estimate is valid for $|\cot(i x\pm \nu)\coth(i x\pm \nu)|^2$. Therefore:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\oint_{\gamma_{\nu}}f_k(z)dz=0.
$$
Thus by the [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) we have:
$$
\operatorname{Res}(f_k,0)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left[\operatorname{Res}(f_k,n\pi)+\operatorname{Res}(f_k,-n\pi)+\operatorname{Res}(f_k,in\pi)+\operatorname{Res}(f_k,-in\pi)\right]=0\tag2
$$

The pole at $z=0$ can be calculated as follows. [Recall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Power_series_expansion) that:
$$
\cot z=\frac1z\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nB_{2n}}{(2n)!}(2z)^{2n};\quad
\coth z=\frac1z\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{B_{2n}}{(2n)!}(2z)^{2n},
$$
where $B_n$ are [Bernoulli numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number).

From this one obtains:
$$
\cot z\coth z=\frac1{z^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{A_{n}}{n!}(2z)^{n},\text{ with } 
A_{2n+1}=0,\;A_{2n}=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{2n}{2k}B_{2k}B_{2n-2k}.\tag3
$$
It follows
$$
\operatorname{Res}(f_k,0)=\frac{2^{k+1}A_{k+1}}{(k+1)!}\equiv A^*_{k+1}.\tag4
$$

Next we compute the residues at the simple poles:
$$
\operatorname{Res}(f_k,n\pi)=\lim_{z\to n\pi}(z-n\pi)\frac{\cot z\coth z}{z^{k}}=\lim_{\zeta\to0}\zeta\frac{\cot (\zeta)\coth(\zeta+n\pi)}{(\zeta+n\pi)^{k}}=\frac{\coth(n\pi)}{(n\pi)^{k}},\tag{5a}
$$
and
$$
\operatorname{Res}(f_k,i n\pi)=\lim_{z\to in\pi}(z-in\pi)\frac{\cot z\coth z}{z^{k}}=\lim_{\zeta\to0}\zeta\frac{\cot (\zeta+in\pi)\coth(\zeta)}{(\zeta+i n\pi)^{k}}=\frac{\coth(n\pi)}{i(in\pi)^{k}},\tag{5b}
$$
where we used 
$$\begin{align}
&\lim_{x\to0}x\cot x=\lim_{x\to0}x\coth x=1,\\ 
&\cot(x+n\pi)=\cot(x),\\ 
&\coth(x+in\pi)=\coth(x),\\ 
&\cot(i x)=-i\coth(x).
\end{align}
$$

From $(5)$ one obtains:
$$
\operatorname{Res}(f_k,n\pi)+\operatorname{Res}(f_k,-n\pi)+\operatorname{Res}(f_k,in\pi)+\operatorname{Res}(f_k,-in\pi)
=\begin{cases}
4\dfrac{\coth(n\pi)}{(n\pi)^k},&k=-1\text{ mod }4,\\
0,&k\ne -1\text{ mod }4.\\
\end{cases}\tag6
$$

Combining $(2)$, $(4)$ and $(6)$ one draws two conclusions:
$$A_k=0\text{ for } k\ne 0\text{ mod }4.\tag7$$
$$4\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{\coth(n\pi)}{(n\pi)^{4K-1}}=-A^*_{4K}.\tag8$$

Observe that (7) is non-trivial only for $k=2\text{ mod }4$. No closed-form expression is known for $A_{4K}$ but its calculation using $(3)$ represents no difficulty. The first four values of $A^*_{4K}$ are:
$$
A^*_0=1,\quad A^*_4=-\frac7{45},\quad A^*_8=-\frac{19}{14175},\quad A^*_{12}=-\frac{2906}{212837625}.
$$

Particularly, for $K=2$ one obtains:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{\coth(n\pi)}{n^{7}}=-\dfrac{A^*_{8}\pi^7}4
=\dfrac{19\pi^7}{56700}.$$

---

Using for $n\ne0$ the relation:
$$
B_{2n}=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(2n)!}{(2\pi)^{2n}}2\zeta(2n),
$$
where $\zeta(z)$ is the Riemann zeta-function, the equation $(8)$ can be rewritten as:
$$
\pi\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{\coth(n\pi)}{n^{4K-1}}=
\zeta(4K)-\sum_{k=1}^{2K-1}(-1)^k\zeta(2k)\zeta(4K-2k),
$$
in agreement with previous results for $K=2$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\displaystyle{\coth k\pi =\frac{1}{k\pi }+2k\pi \sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty }{\frac{1}{n^{2}\pi ^{2}+k^{2}\pi ^{2}}}=\frac{1}{k\pi }+\frac{2k}{\pi }\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty }{\frac{1}{n^{2}+k^{2}}}}$$
$$\displaystyle{\frac{\coth k\pi }{k^{7}}=\frac{1}{k^{8}\pi }+\frac{2}{\pi k^{6}}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty }{\frac{1}{n^{2}+k^{2}}}}$$
$$\displaystyle{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty }{\frac{\coth k\pi }{k^{7}}}=\frac{1}{\pi }\cdot \zeta \left( 8 \right)+\frac{2}{\pi }\sum\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty }{\frac{1}{k^{6}}}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty }{\frac{1}{n^{2}+k^{2}}}}$$

$$\displaystyle{S=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty }{\frac{1}{k^{6}}}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty }{\frac{1}{n^{2}+k^{2}}}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty }{\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty }{\frac{1}{k^{6}}\cdot \frac{1}{n^{2}+k^{2}}}}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty }{\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty }{\left( \frac{n^{2}+k^{2}-k^{2}}{k^{6}n^{2}\left( n^{2}+k^{2} \right)} \right)}}}$$

$$\displaystyle{=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty }{\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty }{\left( \frac{1}{k^{6}n^{2}}-\frac{1}{k^{4}n^{2}\left( n^{2}+k^{2} \right)} \right)}}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty }{\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty }{\left( \frac{1}{k^{6}n^{2}}-\frac{n^{2}+k^{2}-k^{2}}{k^{4}n^{4}\left( n^{2}+k^{2} \right)} \right)}}}$$

$$\displaystyle{=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty }{\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty }{\left( \frac{1}{k^{6}n^{2}}-\frac{1}{k^{4}n^{4}}+\frac{1}{k^{2}n^{4}\left( n^{2}+k^{2} \right)} \right)}}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty }{\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty }{\left( \frac{1}{k^{6}n^{2}}-\frac{1}{k^{4}n^{4}}+\frac{n^{2}+k^{2}-k^{2}}{k^{2}n^{6}\left( n^{2}+k^{2} \right)} \right)}}}$$

$$\displaystyle{=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty }{\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty }{\left( \frac{1}{k^{6}n^{2}}-\frac{1}{k^{4}n^{4}}+\frac{1}{k^{2}n^{6}}-\frac{1}{n^{6}\left( n^{2}+k^{2} \right)} \right)}}=\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty }{\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty }{\left( \frac{1}{k^{6}n^{2}}-\frac{1}{k^{4}n^{4}}+\frac{1}{k^{2}n^{6}} \right)}}}$$

$$\displaystyle{=\frac{1}{2}\zeta \left( 2 \right)\zeta \left( 6 \right)-\frac{1}{2}\zeta ^{2}\left( 4 \right)+\frac{1}{2}\zeta \left( 2 \right)\zeta \left( 6 \right)=\zeta \left( 2 \right)\zeta \left( 6 \right)-\frac{\zeta ^{2}\left( 4 \right)}{2}=\zeta \left( 2 \right)\zeta \left( 6 \right)-\frac{\zeta ^{2}\left( 4 \right)}{2}}$$

$$\displaystyle{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty }{\frac{\coth k\pi }{k^{7}}}=\frac{1}{\pi }\cdot \zeta \left( 8 \right)+\frac{2}{\pi }\left( \zeta \left( 2 \right)\cdot \zeta \left( 6 \right)-\frac{\zeta ^{2}\left( 4 \right)}{2} \right)=\frac{1}{\pi }\cdot \frac{\pi ^{8}}{9450}+\frac{1}{\pi }\left( 2\cdot \frac{\pi ^{2}}{6}\cdot \frac{\pi ^{6}}{945}-\left( \frac{\pi ^{4}}{90} \right)^{2} \right)}$$
$$\displaystyle{=\frac{\pi ^{7}}{9450}+\frac{\pi ^{7}}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{945}-\frac{\pi ^{7}}{90^{2}}=\left( \frac{1}{70}+\frac{1}{21}-\frac{1}{60} \right)\frac{\pi ^{7}}{5\cdot 27}=\left( 1-\frac{1}{20} \right)\frac{\pi ^{7}}{3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot 27}=\frac{19\pi ^{7}}{3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot 20\cdot 27}=\frac{19\pi ^{7}}{56700}}$$