# An equivalent for $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{-x\sqrt{n}}$ as $x$ tends to $0^+$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, asymptotics

I would like to obtain an equivalent form for $$
f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{-x\sqrt{n}}
$$ as $x \rightarrow 0^+$. I tried without success to "remove" the $\sqrt{\cdot}$ in the summand by summing over some new index $p$ writing $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} =\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=p^2}^{(p+1)^2-1}$. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**As $x$ tends to $0^+$**, the series goes to infinity and we have

> $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}e^{-x\sqrt{n}} \sim \frac{2}{x^2}. \tag{*}$$

*Proof.*
Let $n\geq 1$. Since $\displaystyle (-\infty,0]\ni t \rightarrow e^{-x\sqrt{t}}$ is a decreasing function, we have 
$$
e^{-x\sqrt{n+1}} \leq e^{-x\sqrt{t}} \leq e^{-x\sqrt{n}}, \quad t \in [n,n+1], \tag1
$$ integrating $(1)$, we get
$$
\int_n^{n+1}e^{-x\sqrt{t}}dt \leq e^{-x\sqrt{n}} \tag2
$$ and
$$
e^{-x\sqrt{n}} \leq \int_{n-1}^{n}e^{-x\sqrt{t}} dt. \tag3
$$
Then, summing $(2)$ for $n\geq0$, gives
$$
\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-x\sqrt{t}}dt \leq \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}e^{-x\sqrt{n}} \tag4
$$
and summing $(3)$ for $n\geq 1$, gives
$$
 \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}e^{-x\sqrt{n}} \leq 1+\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-x\sqrt{t}}dt. \tag5
$$By the change of variable $u=\sqrt{t},$ $t=u^2,$ $dt=2udu$, we readily have
$$
\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-x\sqrt{t}}dt=2\int_0^{+\infty}ue^{-xu}du = \frac{2}{x^2} .\tag6
$$ Hence combining $(4)$, $(5)$ and $(6)$, leads to the desired result $(*)$.

**Remark.** The same reasoning shows that, for $\alpha>0$,

> $$
> f_{\alpha}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}e^{\large-xn^{\alpha}} \sim_{0^+} \frac{\Gamma(1+1/\alpha)}{x^{1/\alpha}}.
> $$

Answer (score 12):

It  seems to have  escaped attention  that this  sum may  be evaluated
using  harmonic  summation  techniques  which can  be  an  instructive
exercise.

Introduce $S_\alpha(x)%$ given by
$$S_\alpha(x) = \sum_{n\ge 1} \exp(-(nx)^\alpha).$$

The sum term is harmonic and  may be evaluated by inverting its Mellin
transform.

Recall the harmonic sum identity
$$\mathfrak{M}\left(\sum_{k\ge 1} \lambda_k g(\mu_k x);s\right) =
\left(\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{\lambda_k}{\mu_k^s} \right) g^*(s)$$
where $g^*(s)$ is the Mellin transform of $g(x).$

In the present case we have
$$\lambda_k = 1, \quad \mu_k = k 
\quad \text{and} \quad
g(x) = \exp(-x^\alpha).$$
We need the Mellin transform $g^*(s)$ of $g(x)$, which is

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-x^\alpha} x^{s-1} dx
= \int_0^\infty e^{-t} t^{(s-1)/\alpha} 
\frac{1}{\alpha} t^{1/\alpha-1} dt
\\ =  \frac{1}{\alpha} \int_0^\infty e^{-t} t^{s/\alpha-1} dt
= \frac{1}{\alpha} \Gamma(s/\alpha).$$

It follows that the Mellin transform $Q(s)$ of the harmonic sum 
$S(x)$ is given by

$$Q(s) = \frac{1}{\alpha} \Gamma(s/\alpha) \zeta(s)
\quad\text{because}\quad
\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{\lambda_k}{\mu_k^s} = 
\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{1}{k^s}
= \zeta(s)$$
for $\Re(s) > 1.$

The  fundamental  strip of  the  transform  of  the base  function  is
$\langle 0,  \infty \rangle$ and  intersecting this with  $\langle 1,
\infty\rangle$ we obtain that the Mellin inversion integral here is

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{3/2-i\infty}^{3/2+i\infty} Q(s)/x^s ds$$
which we evaluate  by shifting it to the left  for an expansion about
zero.

There are two types of poles:  the one from the zeta function at $s=1$
and the ones from the gamma function at $-q\alpha,$ where $q\ge 0.$

We have
$$\mathrm{Res}\left(Q(s)/x^s; s=1\right) = 
\frac{1}{\alpha}\Gamma(1/\alpha) \times \frac{1}{x}
= \frac{\Gamma(1+1/\alpha)}{x}$$
and
$$\mathrm{Res}\left(Q(s)/x^s; s=-q\alpha\right) = 
\frac{1}{\alpha} \times \alpha \frac{(-1)^q}{q!}
\times \zeta(-q\alpha) \times x^{q\alpha} 
\\ = \frac{(-1)^q}{q!} \zeta(-q\alpha) \times x^{q\alpha}.$$

Now there  are two cases, either  $\alpha$ is an even  integer or not.
If it  is, all the poles for  $q>0$ are canceled by  the zeta function
term, leaving just the poles at $s=1$ and at $s=0$ for a result of
$$ S_\alpha(x) \sim
\frac{\Gamma(1+1/\alpha)}{x} - \frac{1}{2}.$$

When $\alpha = 2$ we get
$$S_2(x) = 
- \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2x}
+ \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{-1-i\infty}^{-1+i\infty} Q(s)/x^s ds.$$

Substitute $s=1-t$ in the remainder integral to get
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{2-i\infty}^{2+i\infty} Q(1-t)/x^{1-t} dt
= \frac{1}{x}
\frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{2-i\infty}^{2+i\infty} \frac{1}{2} 
\Gamma\left(\frac{1-t}{2}\right)
\zeta(1-t) x^t  dt.$$

Recall the following variant of the functional equation of the Riemann
Zeta function:
$$\Gamma\left(\frac{1-t}{2}\right) \zeta(1-t)
= \pi^{1/2-t} \Gamma\left(\frac{t}{2}\right) \zeta(t)$$
and substitute it into the remainder integral
to get
$$\frac{1}{x}
\frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{2-i\infty}^{2+i\infty} \frac{1}{2} 
\pi^{1/2-t} \Gamma\left(\frac{t}{2}\right) \zeta(t)
x^t  dt
= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{x}
\frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{2-i\infty}^{2+i\infty}
\frac{1}{2}
\Gamma\left(\frac{t}{2}\right) \zeta(t)
\left(\frac{x}{\pi}\right)^t  dt.$$

Shift this to $\Re(t)=3/2$ (no poles to pick up) and obtain
$$\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{x}
\frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{3/2-i\infty}^{3/2+i\infty}
\frac{1}{2}
\Gamma\left(\frac{t}{2}\right) \zeta(t)
\left(\frac{x}{\pi}\right)^t  dt
= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{x} S_2(\pi/x).$$

This yields the functional equation
$$S_2(x) = 
- \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2x}
+ \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{x} S_2(\pi/x).$$
which is a variant of Jacobi's theta function identity.

Returning to the main thread we observe that
when $\alpha$ is not an even integer we have the expansion

$$ S_\alpha(x) \sim
\frac{\Gamma(1+1/\alpha)}{x} - \frac{1}{2}
+ \sum_{q\ge 1} 
\frac{(-1)^q}{q!} \zeta(-q\alpha) \times x^{q\alpha}.$$

The  study  of the  convergence  properties  of  this expansion  is  a
delicate  matter  and  certainly  a  wonderful  challenge.  E.g.  with
$\alpha$ an odd  integer we get a non-zero  contribution from the zeta
function terms but we have
$$\zeta(-q\alpha) = - \frac{B_{q\alpha+1}}{q\alpha + 1}
\quad\text{and}\quad
|B_{2n}| \sim 4\sqrt{\pi n} \left(\frac{n}{\pi e}\right)^{2n}$$

so  the zeta  function  values outgrow  the  factorial in  $q$ and the
expansion eventually diverges.

The following table illustrates the process when calculating $S_3(1/2)$:

```
1.285959023138498e+00
1.284917356471832e+00
1.284919822538751e+00
1.284919709811953e+00
1.284919736441052e+00
1.284919716423841e+00
1.284919753275291e+00
1.284919612356084e+00
1.284920611708108e+00
1.284908513429109e+00
1.285143226270321e+00
1.278200633277179e+00
1.578934319042731e+00
-1.687446462625181e+01
1.542969266697830e+03
-1.758244058759777e+05
2.640441955632738e+07
-5.130529386490404e+09
1.270035750847759e+12
-3.950618113631400e+14
1.525356085967402e+17
```

The correct value is $1.2849300884351988591.$

Similarly when computing $S_5(1/3)$ we get the table

```
2.254506227199282e+00
2.254522557462526e+00
2.254522552313936e+00
2.254522552853181e+00
2.254522551342709e+00
2.254522594231955e+00
2.254515285982698e+00
2.259889649827273e+00
-1.133507270756404e+01
1.002166612666027e+05
-1.897690119553089e+09
8.353404075737941e+13
-7.886089945242315e+18
1.493955388567194e+24
-5.370850993208232e+29
3.494071363049499e+35
-3.948314085212110e+41
7.478102802029752e+47
-2.300704020425045e+54
1.118323430713735e+61
-8.378457528967820e+67
```

The correct value is $2.2551776136424966417$.

To conclude we recall that the sum proposed for evaluation was slightly
different, namely
$$f_\alpha(x) = \sum_{n\ge 0} \exp(-x n^\alpha).$$
This is readily seen to be equal to
$$S_\alpha(x^{1/\alpha}) + 1$$
and hence
$$f_\alpha(x) \sim
\frac{\Gamma(1+1/\alpha)}{x^{1/\alpha}} + \frac{1}{2}
+ \sum_{q\ge 1} 
\frac{(-1)^q}{q!} \zeta(-q\alpha) \times x^q.$$

There is a similar calculation at this 
[MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/991066/).

Comment: Thanks for sharing these interesting results! It reminds me the indispensable book from Flajolet and Sedgewick : http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/books.html

Comment: The work of Flajolet is the defining moment of mathematical computer science in the twentieth century. Keep in mind though that the inspiration for the functional equation for $S_2(x)$ is from the paper "Mellin Transform and its Applications" by Szpankowski.

Comment: I can see that our case is considered here with Mellin transform (example 14, p. 33):http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/FlGoDu95.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the pointer which I wasn't aware of. Good to know that I got the same formula. Of course if one stopped working on problems that have been treated by Flajolet and Sedgewick we would all be out of work, their contribution is that comprehensive.

Comment: Yes, Flajolet and his team did a *vast* and *profound* work.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
With [Abel-Plana Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Abel-PlanaFormula.html) :

> \begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\expo{-x\root{n}}}
> \\[5mm]&=\ \overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-x\root{t}}\,\dd t}
> ^{\ds{\color{#c00000}{\root{t}\ \mapsto\ t}}}\ +\
> \left.\half\,\expo{-x\root{t}}\right\vert_{\, t\ =\ 0} +\ic\int_{0}^{\infty}
> {\expo{-x\root{\ic t}} - \expo{-x\root{-\ic t}} \over \expo{2\pi t} - 1}\,\dd t
> \\[5mm]&=2\ \overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-xt}t\,\dd t}
> ^{\ds{\color{#c00000}{1 \over x^{2}}}}\ +\
> \half - 2\Im\int_{0}^{\infty}
> {\exp\pars{-x\root{t}\pars{1 + \ic}/\root{2}} \over \expo{2\pi t} - 1}\,\dd t
> \\[5mm]&={2 \over x^{2}} + {1 \over 2}
> +2\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\pars{-\,{x \over \root{2}}\,\root{t}}\,{\sin\pars{\root{2}x\root{t}/2} \over \expo{2\pi t} - 1}\,\dd t
> \\[5mm]&\sim\color{#66f}{\large{2 \over x^{2}} + {1 \over 2}
> +\ \underbrace{\pars{\root{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\root{t} \over \expo{2\pi t} - 1}\,\dd t}}_{\ds{\color{#c00000}{{\zeta\pars{3/2} \over 4\pi}\ \color{#000}{\approx\ 0.2079}}}}\
> x
> \quad\mbox{when}\quad x \sim 0}
> \end{align}

$$
\color{#66f}{\large\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\expo{-x\root{n}} \sim {2 \over x^{2}}\,,
\qquad x \sim 0}
$$

> Here, we can see a plot of the difference
>   $\ds{\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\expo{-x\root{n}} -
> \bracks{{2 \over x^{2}} + \half + {\zeta\pars{3/2} \over 4\pi}\,x}}$:
>   [image]

Comment: (+1). Nice work. You seem to have used the Mellin transform $$\mathfrak{M}\left(\frac{1}{e^x-1}; s\right) = \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x-1} dx = \Gamma(s)\zeta(s).$$ We use the functional equation of the Riemann Zeta function to verify that your coefficient on $x$ is the same as mine.

Comment: Can you maybe explain how you simplified the numerator in the integral at the end of the first line? I get $$e^{-x\sqrt{it}}-e^{-x\sqrt{-it}} =e^{-x\sqrt{t}(1+i)/\sqrt{2}}-e^{-x\sqrt{t}(1-i)/\sqrt{2}} = - 2i e^{-x\sqrt{t}/\sqrt{2}} \sin(x\sqrt{t}/\sqrt{2}).$$

Comment: @MarkoRiedel It was a typo. I just fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: Do you maybe want to take another look at the integral on the second line?

Comment: @FelixMarin Nice point of view! (+1).

Comment: @OlivierOloa Thanks. I like very much Abel-Plana.