# Cauchy-Ramanujan Formula $ \displaystyle \sum_{\stackrel{m \in \mathbb{Z}}{m \neq 0}} \frac{\coth m \pi}{m^{4p+3}} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, zeta-functions, bernoulli-numbers

Cauchy and Ramanujan both gave the formula:

$$  \sum_{\stackrel{m \in \mathbb{Z}}{m \neq 0}} \frac{\coth m \pi}{m^{4p+3}}  = (2\pi)^{4p+3}\sum_{k=0}^{2p+2} (-1)^{k+1}
\frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!}\frac{B_{4(p+1)-2k}}{(4(p+1)-2k)!}
 $$

If we lightly manipulate things, we can use a bit of umbral calculus to simplify the formula

\begin{eqnarray}  -\frac{[4(p+1)]!}{(2\pi)^{4p+3}}\sum_{\stackrel{m \in \mathbb{Z}}{m \neq 0}} \frac{\coth m \pi}{m^{4p+3}}  &=& \sum_{k=0}^{2p+2} (-1)^{k}
\binom{4(p+1)}{2k}B_{2k}B_{4(p+1)-2k} \\
&=& \frac{1}{2}\left[ (B+iB)^{2(p+1)}+(B-iB)^{2(p+1)}\right]
\end{eqnarray}

It's still a mess, but at least we have normalization.  Prove LHS = RHS

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: It's the very last sentence. More of request than a question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Method of proof of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\tfrac{\coth n\pi}{n^7}=\tfrac{19}{56700}\pi^7$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/991066/method-of-proof-of-sum-limits-n-1-infty-tfrac-coth-n-pin7-tfrac19)

Answer (score 6):

Note that this sum is in fact
$$2\sum_{m\ge 1} \frac{\coth m\pi}{m^{4p+3}}.$$

The sum term  $$T_p(x) = 
2\sum_{m\ge 1} \frac{\coth mx}{m^{4p+3}}$$
is harmonic and may be evaluated by inverting its Mellin transform.

Observe that $$\coth x = \frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{e^x-e^{-x}}
= 1 + 2\frac{e^{-x}}{e^x-e^{-x}}
= 1 + 2\frac{e^{-2x}}{1-e^{-2x}}.$$

This yields
$$T_p(x) = 2\zeta(4p+3) + 
4\sum_{m\ge 1} \frac{1}{m^{4p+3}} \frac{e^{-2mx}}{1-e^{-2mx}}.$$

We will now work with
$$S(x) = \sum_{m\ge 1} \frac{1}{m^{4p+3}} 
\frac{e^{-2mx}}{1-e^{-2mx}}$$
and establish a  functional equation for $S(x)$ that has  $x=\pi$ as a
fixed point.

Recall the harmonic sum identity
$$\mathfrak{M}\left(\sum_{k\ge 1} \lambda_k g(\mu_k x);s\right) =
\left(\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{\lambda_k}{\mu_k^s} \right) g^*(s)$$
where $g^*(s)$ is the Mellin transform of $g(x).$

In the present case we have
$$\lambda_k = \frac{1}{k^{4p+3}}, 
\quad \mu_k = k \quad \text{and} \quad
g(x) = \frac{\exp(-2x)}{1-\exp(-2x)}.$$

We need the Mellin transform $g^*(s)$ of $g(x)$
which we compute as follows:
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\exp(-2x)}{1-\exp(-2x)} x^{s-1} dx
= \int_0^\infty \sum_{q\ge 1} \exp(-2qx)\; x^{s-1} dx
\\ = \sum_{q\ge 1} \int_0^\infty \exp(-2qx)\; x^{s-1} dx
= \Gamma(s) \sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{1}{2^s q^s}
= \frac{1}{2^s} \Gamma(s) \zeta(s).$$

with fundamental strip $\langle 1,\infty \rangle.$

Hence the Mellin transform $Q(s)$ of $S(x)$ is given by
$$ Q(s) = \frac{1}{2^s} \Gamma(s) \zeta(s) \zeta(s+4p+3)
\quad\text{because}\quad
\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{\lambda_k}{\mu_k^s} = \zeta(s+4p+3)$$
where $\Re(s+4p+3) > 1$ or $\Re(s) > -4p-2$.

Intersecting the  fundamental strip and  the half-plane from  the zeta
function  term we  find  that  the Mellin  inversion  integral for  an
expansion about zero is
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{3/2-i\infty}^{3/2+i\infty} Q(s)/x^s ds$$
which we evaluate in the left half-plane $\Re(s)<3/2.$

The plain zeta  function term cancels the poles of  the gamma function
term  at even  negative  integers  $2q\le -2$  and  the compound  zeta
function term the  poles at odd negative integers  $2q+1\le -4p-5$. We
are left with the contributions from $s=1$, $s=0$ and $s=-1$ which are

$$\begin{align}
\mathrm{Res}(Q(s)/x^s; s=1) & = \frac{1}{2x}\zeta(4p+4) \\
\mathrm{Res}(Q(s)/x^s; s=0) & = -\frac{1}{2}\zeta(4p+3) \\
\mathrm{Res}(Q(s)/x^s; s=-1) & = \frac{1}{6} x\zeta(4p+2).
\end{align}$$

The remaining contributions are
$$\sum_{q=1}^{2p+1} \mathrm{Res}(Q(s)/x^s; s=-2q-1)
\\ = \sum_{q=1}^{2p+1} 2^{2q+1} x^{2q+1} 
\frac{(-1)^{2q+1}}{(2q+1)!}
\zeta(-2q-1) \zeta(4p+2-2q)
\\ = \sum_{q=1}^{2p+1} 2^{2q+1} x^{2q+1} 
\frac{1}{(2q+1)!}
\frac{B_{2q+2}}{2q+2}
(-1)^{2p+1-q+1} \frac{B_{4p+2-2q}(2\pi)^{4p+2-2q}}{2(4p+2-2q)!}
\\ = \sum_{q=1}^{2p+1} 2^{2q+1} x^{2q+1} 
\frac{B_{2q+2}}{(2q+2)!}
(-1)^{-q} \frac{B_{4p+2-2q}(2\pi)^{4p+2-2q}}{2(4p+2-2q)!}
\\ = \sum_{q=2}^{2p+2} 2^{2q-1} x^{2q-1} 
\frac{B_{2q}}{(2q)!}
(-1)^{q+1} \frac{B_{4p+4-2q}(2\pi)^{4p+4-2q}}{2(4p+4-2q)!}
\\ = 2^{4p+2} \sum_{q=2}^{2p+2} x^{2q-1} 
\frac{B_{2q}}{(2q)!}
(-1)^{q+1} \frac{B_{4p+4-2q}\pi^{4p+4-2q}}{(4p+4-2q)!}
\\ = 2^{4p+2} \sum_{q=2}^{2p+2} x^{2q-1} \pi^{4p+4-2q}
\frac{B_{2q}}{(2q)!}
(-1)^{q+1} \frac{B_{4p+4-2q}}{(4p+4-2q)!}$$

and  the one  from the  pole  of the  compound zeta  function term  at
$s=-4p-2$ which we'll do in a moment.

Now  some algebra  shows  that  setting $q=0$  and  $q=1$  in the  sum
produces precisely the  values that we obtained earlier  for the poles
at $s=1$ and $s=-1$ so we may extend the sum to start at zero, keeping
only the residue from the pole at $s=0$ to get
$$2^{4p+2} \sum_{q=0}^{2p+2} x^{2q-1} \pi^{4p+4-2q}
\frac{B_{2q}}{(2q)!}
(-1)^{q+1} \frac{B_{4p+4-2q}}{(4p+4-2q)!}.$$

We have thus established that
$$S(x) = -\frac{1}{2}\zeta(4p+3) 
+ \mathrm{Res}(Q(s)/x^s; s=-4p-2)
\\ + 2^{4p+2} \sum_{q=0}^{2p+2} x^{2q-1} \pi^{4p+4-2q}
\frac{B_{2q}}{(2q)!}
(-1)^{q+1} \frac{B_{4p+4-2q}}{(4p+4-2q)!}
\\ + \frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{-4p-4-i\infty}^{-4p-4+i\infty} Q(s)/x^s ds.$$

To  treat the  integral recall  the duplication  formula of  the gamma
function:
$$\Gamma(s) = 
\frac{1}{\sqrt\pi} 2^{s-1} 
\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)
\Gamma\left(\frac{s+1}{2}\right).$$

which yields for the integral
$$\int_{-4p-4-i\infty}^{-4p-4+i\infty} 
\frac{1}{2\sqrt\pi} 
\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)
\Gamma\left(\frac{s+1}{2}\right)
\zeta(s) 
\zeta(s+4p+3)/x^s ds.$$

Furthermore observe  the following variant of  the functional equation
of the Riemann zeta function:
$$\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)\zeta(s)
= \pi^{s-1/2} \Gamma\left(\frac{1-s}{2}\right)
\zeta(1-s)$$

which gives for the integral
$$\int_{-4p-4-i\infty}^{-4p-4+i\infty} 
\frac{\pi^{s-1}}{2}
\Gamma\left(\frac{s+1}{2}\right)
\Gamma\left(\frac{1-s}{2}\right)
\zeta(1-s)
\zeta(s+4p+3)/x^s ds
\\ = \int_{-4p-4-i\infty}^{-4p-4+i\infty} 
\frac{\pi^{s}}{2}
\frac{1}{\sin(\pi/2(s+1))}
\zeta(1-s)
\zeta(s+4p+3)/x^s ds.$$

Now put $s=-4p-2-u$ to get
$$\int_{2-i\infty}^{2+i\infty} 
\frac{\pi^{-4p-2-u}}{2}
\frac{1}{\sin(\pi/2(-4p-2-u+1))}
\\ \times \zeta(u+4p+3)
\zeta(1-u)/x^{-4p-2-u} du
\\ = \frac{x^{4p+2}}{\pi^{4p+2}}
 \int_{2-i\infty}^{2+i\infty} 
\frac{\pi^{-u}}{2}
\frac{1}{\sin(\pi/2(-(u+1)))}
\\ \times \zeta(u+4p+3)
\zeta(1-u)/x^{-u} du
\\ = - \frac{x^{4p+2}}{\pi^{4p+2}}
 \int_{2-i\infty}^{2+i\infty} 
\frac{\pi^{-u}}{2}
\frac{1}{\sin(\pi/2(u+1))}
\\ \times \zeta(u+4p+3)
\zeta(1-u)/x^{-u} du.$$

We have established the functional equation
$$S(x) = -\frac{1}{2}\zeta(4p+3) 
+ \mathrm{Res}(Q(s)/x^s; s=-4p-2)
\\ + 2^{4p+2} \sum_{q=0}^{2p+2} x^{2q-1} \pi^{4p+4-2q}
\frac{B_{2q}}{(2q)!}
(-1)^{q+1} \frac{B_{4p+4-2q}}{(4p+4-2q)!}
-\left(\frac{x}{\pi}\right)^{4p+2} S\left(\frac{\pi^2}{x}\right).$$

Setting $x=\pi$ we have
$$S(\pi) = -\frac{1}{2}\zeta(4p+3) 
+ \mathrm{Res}(Q(s)/\pi^s; s=-4p-2)
\\ + 2^{4p+2} \pi^{4p+3} \sum_{q=0}^{2p+2} 
\frac{B_{2q}}{(2q)!}
(-1)^{q+1} \frac{B_{4p+4-2q}}{(4p+4-2q)!}
-\left(\frac{\pi}{\pi}\right)^{4p+2} S\left(\pi\right)$$
and hence
$$S(\pi) = -\frac{1}{4}\zeta(4p+3) 
+ \frac{1}{2} \mathrm{Res}(Q(s)/\pi^s; s=-4p-2)
\\ + 2^{4p+1} \pi^{4p+3} \sum_{q=0}^{2p+2} 
\frac{B_{2q}}{(2q)!}
(-1)^{q+1} \frac{B_{4p+4-2q}}{(4p+4-2q)!}.$$

To conclude we treat the residue that we have defered until now.
Recall the alternate form of $Q(s)/\pi^s,$
$$\frac{\pi^{s}}{2}
\frac{1}{\sin(\pi/2(s+1))}
\zeta(1-s)
\zeta(s+4p+3)/\pi^s
\\ = \frac{1}{2}
\frac{1}{\sin(\pi/2(s+1))}
\zeta(1-s)
\zeta(s+4p+3).$$
It follows that the residue at $s=-4p-2$ is
$$\frac{1}{2}
\frac{1}{\sin(\pi/2(-4p-1))}
\zeta(4p+3)
= \frac{1}{2}
\frac{1}{\sin(-\pi/2)}
\zeta(4p+3) = -\frac{1}{2} \zeta(4p+3).$$

This finally yields for $S(\pi)$
$$S(\pi) = 
-\frac{1}{2}\zeta(4p+3) 
+ 2^{4p+1} \pi^{4p+3} \sum_{q=0}^{2p+2} 
\frac{B_{2q}}{(2q)!}
(-1)^{q+1} \frac{B_{4p+4-2q}}{(4p+4-2q)!}.$$

Computing $T_p(\pi)$ we thus obtain
$$2\zeta(4p+3)
-4\times\frac{1}{2}\zeta(4p+3) 
+ 2^{4p+3} \pi^{4p+3} \sum_{q=0}^{2p+2} 
\frac{B_{2q}}{(2q)!}
(-1)^{q+1} \frac{B_{4p+4-2q}}{(4p+4-2q)!}$$
or
$$(2\pi)^{4p+3} \sum_{q=0}^{2p+2} 
\frac{B_{2q}}{(2q)!}
(-1)^{q+1} \frac{B_{4p+4-2q}}{(4p+4-2q)!},$$
QED.

The  inspiration  for  this  calculation  is from  the  paper  "Mellin
Transform and its Applications" by Szpankowski.

Comment: Thank you for these kind words.

Comment: Again as in your another post you made a connection between $S(x)$ and $S(\pi^2/x)$. But how did you relate each other since integral with $Q(s)$ and the one with sine in the denominator are note the same? I would be glad where was the point of establishing the functional relation.

Comment: Nice derivation. Btw, Is this your own proof of did you read it somewhere?

Comment: @BooleanWick. The proof is mine but I make no claim to originality of the method. For sources consult "Mellin Transform Asymptotics" by Flajolet and Sedgewick INRIA RR 2956 as well as the Mellin transform material in Szpankowski's "Average Case Analysis of Algorithms on Sequences" as mentioned in the post.

Comment: I also recommend "On Plouffe's Ramanujan Identities" by L. Vepstas.

Answer (score 4):

There is also a way to obtain this formula using the partial fraction expansion of cotangent:
$$ \frac{\pi}{2x} \coth(\pi x) - \frac{1}{2x^2} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2+x^2} $$
Let $m\geq 0$ be an integer, set $x=n$, divide by $n^{4m+2}$ and then sum from $n=1$ to infinity to get
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\pi}{2n^{4m+3}} \coth(\pi n) - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2n^{4m+4}} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{4m+2}(k^2+n^2)} $$
The sum on the right may be handled by switching the order of summation (justified by absolute convergence) and then rewriting things as follows:
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{4m}} \frac{1}{n^2(k^2+n^2)} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{4m}k^2} \left(\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{k^2+n^2} \right) = \zeta(4m+2)\zeta(2) - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{4m}k^2(k^2+n^2)} $$
Repeating the procedure results in
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{4m+2}(k^2+n^2)} = \zeta(4m+2)\zeta(2) - \zeta(4m)\zeta(4) + \cdots + \zeta(2) \zeta(4m+2) - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^{4m+2}(k^2+n^2)}$$
The final sum is the same as the first if we switch the dummy variables, and so we have that
$$ 2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{4m+2}(k^2+n^2)} = 2 \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} (-1)^k \zeta(4m+2-2k) \zeta(2k+2) +(-1)^m \zeta^2(2m+2) $$
Replacing this in the equality above and cleaning up a bit gives the result
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\coth(\pi n)}{n^{4m+3}} = \frac{\zeta(4m+4)}{\pi} + \frac{2}{\pi} \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} (-1)^k \zeta(4m+2-2k)\zeta(2k+2) + \frac{(-1)^m}{\pi} \zeta^2(2m+2) $$
This may be expressed in the form you wrote by using the well known formula for zeta at the even integers.

Comment: Formula $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\coth(\pi n)}{n^{4m+3}} = \frac{\zeta(4m+4)}{\pi} + \frac{2}{\pi} \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \zeta(4m+2-2k)\zeta(2k+2) + \frac{(-1)^m}{\pi} \zeta^2(2m+2) $$ dosen't work for $m>1$ ? Gives incorrect values.?

Comment: Which values are incorrect?

Comment: For example `m=2`. With Mathematica:`{f[m_] := 
  Zeta[4 m + 4]/Pi + 
   2/Pi*Sum[Zeta[4 m + 2 - 2 k]*Zeta[2 k + 2], {k, 0, m - 1}] + (-1)^
     m/Pi*Zeta[2 m + 2]^2, f[2] // N}` give me:`2.38791` but correct answer is: `1.00424`.

Comment: I have corrected the formula. There was a $(-1)^k$ factor missing before. Thanks for catching the mistake

Comment: Thanks,now it's ok.

Comment: @Dave Nice derivation btw. Is this your own approach or have you read this derivation somewhere else already? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! I saw the method used on a special case here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/991066/method-of-proof-of-sum-limits-n-1-infty-tfrac-coth-n-pin7-tfrac19 and generalized it. The method also works for finding three other classes series if you start with the partial fractions for tanh, csch, and sech.