# Verify the closed form of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\coth\pi k}{ke^{\pi k}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, closed-form, hyperbolic-functions, zeta-functions

Verify the closed form of $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\coth\pi
 k}{ke^{\pi
 k}}=\frac{\pi}{12}+\ln\left(1-e^{-\pi}\right)-\frac{1}{4}\ln2\tag{1}$$

> This is in spirit of many such formulas like; $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\coth\pi k}{k^{3}}=\frac{7\pi^{3}}{180},\hspace{.2cm}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\coth\pi k}{k^{7}}=\frac{19\pi^{7}}{56700}, .. \tag{for odd powers}$$

And I believe odd numbers of the form $4n-1$. Since, $\sum \coth{\pi k}/k$ is diverging, Eq $1$, could take it's place. And also is there any generalizations for the same?

Comment: If I may ask,  how did you find this closed form ?

Comment: Such sums were handled by Ramanujan in very general form. See the general result at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1293232/72031

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can write!
$$ \frac{\coth(tk)}{k \;\exp(tk)} = - \frac{1}{k\; \exp(tk)} + \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{2}{k\; \exp((2j+1)tk)} $$ 
converging absolutely for $t > 0$.  Thus

$$\eqalign{ \sum_{k=1}^\infty  \frac{\coth(tk)}{k \exp(tk)} &= 
- \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k \exp(tk)} + \sum_{j=0}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2}{k\; \exp((2j+1)tk)}\cr
&= -\ln(1-\exp(-t)) - 2 \sum_{j=0}^\infty \ln(1-\exp(-(2j+1)t))}$$
Now
$$ \sum_{j=0}^\infty \ln(1 - \exp(-(2j+1)t)) = \ln \left(\prod_{j=0}^\infty (1 - \exp(-(2j+1)t))\right) $$
It looks to me like for $t = \pi$ that product is $\exp(-\pi/24)\; 2^{1/8}$, but I don't have a proof.
If that's the case, we would have

$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty  \frac{\coth(\pi k)}{k \exp(\pi k)} = - \ln(1 - \exp(-\pi))  + \frac{\pi}{12} - \frac{1}{4} \ln(2)$$

EDIT:  Hmmm.  Actually we have (see formula (60) [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InfiniteProduct.html))
$$ \prod_{j=0}^\infty \left(1 - \frac{1}{x^{2j+1}}\right) =
x^{-1/24} \theta_4(0,x^{-1})^{1/2} \left(\frac{2}{\theta_1'(0,x^{-1})}\right)^{1/6} $$
and I don't know if that will simplify to 
$\exp(-\pi/24) 2^{1/8}$ for $x = \exp(\pi)$, though it is very close numerically.

EDIT: Double hmmm: using identities for Jacobi Theta functions, the desired equality comes down to (in Maple's notation)

$$  \text{EllipticK}(\sqrt{2}/2) =
\int_0^1 \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2} \sqrt{1-t^2/2}} = \frac{\pi^{3/2}}{2 \;\Gamma(3/4)^2}$$

In Mathematica notation that is $K(1/2)$, and a formula [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegrals/EllipticK/03/01/) implies that this is true.

Comment: Actually it is given in formula (49). Great answer btw.

Comment: Ramanujan gives his definition of class invariant $g_n$ as $$g_n=2^{-1/4}e^{\pi\sqrt{n}/24}\prod_{j=1}^{\infty} (1-e^{-(2j-1)\pi\sqrt{n}})$$ and it is well known that $g_1=2^{-1/8}$. This matches with what you have given in your post. +1